# Слово "фармазон"

Tags: этимология, лексика

Что означает слово "фармазон"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устаревшее слово "фармазон" на воровском жаргоне означало "жулик", "мошенник", "вор". Происходит оно от слова "франкмасон" и появилось, скорее всего, после того, как Александр I своим указом изгнал масонов из России.